# How to use bigquery to test if string in list of strings with wildcards

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to write something equivalent to the below, but it appears not to work. Is this possible in BigQuery?

```sql
select *
from table
where lower(field1) in ("%foo%", "%bar%", "%baz%")
```

I also need this functionality inside a `case when` clause

```sql
case when (lower(field1) in ("%foo%", "%bar%")) then "string1"
else "string2" end as NewField
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select *
from table
where regexp_contains(lower(field1), r'foo|bar|baz')
```